# How to count single days of multiple records between dates that are grouped by week

Tags: mysql

I have a table that stores logs for activities on jobs.

This query groups on weeks, I use `numofdays` to determine the days worked during the week, and have other columns that multiply this value to calculate other reports.

Up until recently this has worked fine until I took a day off this week on Tuesday.

My problem is the value of `numofdays` is calculated on the earliest and latest activities logged for the grouped week. This works fine if holiday was taken at the start or end of weeks, but not a day in the middle ( with working days on either side)

I think what I want to do is count on the days grouped by day within the period of the group.

If I had logged activities m,w,t,f then this would return 4 for the value of `numofdays`. This then makes my `DATEDIFF` calculation. below void.

```sql
SELECT  
    CONCAT(YEAR(start_timedate), '/', WEEK(start_timedate)) AS week_name,
    DATEDIFF(
        max(
            IF(
                end_timedate = '00-00-00 00:00:00',
                NOW(),
                end_timedate
            )
        ),
        min(
            IF(
                start_timedate = '00-00-00 00:00:00',
                NOW(),
                start_timedate
            )
        )
    ) + 1 numofdays

    FROM timesheet WHERE employee_id = 21 AND yearweek(start_timedate) = yearweek(curdate());

    GROUP BY week_name

ORDER BY
  YEAR(start_timedate) ASC,
  WEEK(start_timedate) ASC;
```

Above is an abbreviated version of my existing query, is my only option a subquery here?Feels kind of ugly...

Here is an example of the one way I have retrieved the result expected via a subquery and a derived table. I am repeating myself which makes me feel like there are better solutions to learn from.

```sql
SELECT  
CONCAT(YEAR(start_timedate), '/', WEEK(start_timedate)) AS week_name,
(
    SELECT  count(*)
        FROM (
        SELECT DAY(start_timedate) 
            FROM timesheet  t
            WHERE t.employee_id = 21
            AND yearweek(start_timedate) = yearweek(curdate())
            GROUP BY DAY(start_timedate)            
        ) working_days
) numofdays

FROM timesheet WHERE employee_id = 21 AND yearweek(start_timedate) = yearweek(curdate())

GROUP BY
  week_name
ORDER BY
  YEAR(start_timedate) ASC,
  WEEK(start_timedate) ASC;
```

Comment: Try a Windowing Function (MySQL 8.0) and partition by date

Comment: @DaveStokes I should have mentioned, I am using MySQL 5.6 so this doesn't appear to be an option available to me.